# Use of brackets around parameters when creating a stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I've recently spotted a few stored procedures declared with `()` brackets around the parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema].[Table]
(
    @Param1 char(3),
    @Param2 bit,
    @Param3 datetimeoffset(0)
)
```

I immediately went to the [MS docs site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) but they're not saying anything about it and neither can I find anything on a web search.

The encasing of the parameters don't seem to cause any issues and when I dump the stored procedure using SSMS, it happily dumps it with the brackets (obviously because it's stored the original definition, just saying):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema].[Table]
(
    @Param1 char(3),
    @Param2 bit,
    @Param3 datetimeoffset(0)
)
```

Whilst it's "allowed", yet undocumented, how valid is this declaration and is it good or bad? Apparently it was done to standardise the way both functions and stored procedures are declared.

Comment: It is purely preference. Unlike a function, parameters for a Stored Procedure do not *need* to be within parentheses. You could lump this in the same category as some people prefer `MyColumn AS Alias`, some `Alias = MyColumn`, and others just `MyColumn Alias`.

Comment: This is how I write all my stored procedures. I don't really remember why but that's how I've learned to write them. I think it might have been mandatory in older  (like, really older - 2000) versions.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad - I will retract...

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I could be wrong but I don't ever remember having to enclose parameter definitions in parenthesis. I've been using SQL Server since version 4.21, over 25 years ago. I never use them myself.

Comment: Had a look through the [Deprecated Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017) as well, and I can't see anything that suggests that it'll become mandatory to put the parameters in parentheses in the future (like the use of `;` to terminate your statements).

Comment: The fact that parentheses are allowed is indeed not documented (in the formal syntax, at least, it's included even in the examples on the same page), and curiously has not been documented for a very long time (going back to at least SQL Server 2005 Books Online), but it has worked for at least that long. There is no chance of that syntax ever getting deprecated suddenly, so the docs should probably change. Fortunately these days anyone can propose an edit.

Comment: @DanGuzman Your history is longer than mine. I've started with SQL Server 7 and almost immediately upgraded to 2000. Using parenthesis was probably just in the tutorials I've been reading back then.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your valuable feedback (including that hilarious 500).  Appreciate the prompt responses.